# How to read excel files from sharepoint without save it on pc Office365-REST-Python

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint, bytesio

I need to read the contents of an excel file stored in sharepoint and convert it into a dataframe without saving it on my pc. But at this point I need assistance to point me in the right direction

The code goes like this:

- login on sharepoint
- get the content of an .xlsx file
- load that content into a pandas dataframe
- return the dataframe object

I'm using Office365-REST-Python-Client library
I do not know where is my mistake but at the end I got the following error:

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import io
import json
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.runtime.http.request_options import RequestOptions
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import pandas as pd

SITEURL="https://{my company name}.sharepoint.com/sites/{my site}"
FILE_URL="Documentos%20compartidos/Test/Test2.xlsx"
PASSWORD="{my password}"
USERNAME="{my user name/ mail}"

# sharepoint core login
async def loging():
    username=USERNAME
    password=PASSWORD
    site_url=SITEURL
    file_url=FILE_URL
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential(f"{username}", f"{password}"))
    
    request = RequestOptions("{0}/_api/web/".format(site_url))
    response = ctx.pending_request().execute_request_direct(request)
    ajson = json.loads(response.content)
    web_title = ajson['d']['Title']
    print(web_title)  # this print help me to confirm that I logged in

    ctx.load(ctx.web)
    ctx.execute_query()

    response = File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)
    bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
    bytes_file_obj.seek(0)

    df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, engine='openpyxl')  #<-- here I got the error. 
    # without the "engine='openpyxl'", I've got another error asking for an explicit engine 

    return df
```

Thanks in advance.